# How to use 了 in Chinese?

Tags: meaning, usage, dictionary

I know 了 is a indicator for past tense in Chinese. But it seems there are more usages for this character, so how to use 了 in Chinese?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably look it up in a dictionary. Foreign learners won't remember, and native speakers can't make a list, native language is almost an instinct, we won't remember every usages.